# Identify SharePoint Site is Archived or not

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, web, archive

I want to generate a report in which I want to list all the sites in my web applications that are archived?

I am using Server Side code.

Is there any specific property available which specifies that the particular site is archived or not?

Comment: I don't think there's a **property** that you can check to see if the site has been **Archived**. Because, I think, archiving means moving content from its current location to another location within current farm to another farm. And that you can do with the custom script or 3rd-party tool. There are of course **Retention Policy**, you can read [here](https://www.sharepointeurope.com/archiving-in-sharepoint/), and also **ReadOnly** state, you can read [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/set-spsite?view=sharepoint-ps)

Answer (score 0):

Mostly like Matiur said, in SharePoint we do not have such property as there are different ways to archive documents, records, list items. For sites, we may [lock it](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sites/manage-the-lock-status-for-site-collections), close it, export it as a file or use some 3rd-party tools to archive it in their way.